# How can I reflect state in input?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks

I am implementing the search function using react-query and react-hook-form.
There is also a recent search word function in the function I create.
When I click on a recent search word, I want it to be visible in the input field.

The code I wrote is as follows.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('');

const handleRecentWord = ({word}) => {
  setValue(word);
};

return (
  <>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Input
        type="text"
        placeholder="please enter keyword"
        register={register('word')}
        defaultValue={value ? value : ''}
      />
    </form>
    ...
    <li onClick={() => handleRecentWord(data.word)}>
      {data.word}
    </li>
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're desctructuring your `word` when you pass it to the `handleRecentWord` function. You can just take the word argument.

```
const handleRecentWord = (word: string) => {
  setValue(word);
};
```